# How to send E-mail and SMS notifications when one user outbid another user in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am new to auction idea of drupal 7. My client wants an checkbox to be implemented ,where users can select whether they require any e-mail notification /sms or both or none.I want to send e-mail and sms notification to the respective logged in user on the basis of bids placed by them!

I configured the mail and sms notifcation part .Can anyone let me  know how to send notifications when user checks the checkbox in drupal 7 on the basis of bid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to user28867's answer which gives a useful way to send messages to users, you seem to need a way to trigger those messages.

Assuming the trigger is based on saving a node of some kind you should look at [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) which will tell you when a node is saved.

[Create a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7) to receive that message and act on the hook by creating a function that [implements the hook](https://www.drupal.org/node/292).

Of course the standard warnings apply:

- Make sure you have replace 'hook' with the name of your module.
- Clear the cache before trying it out as Drupal doesn't look for hooks on boot or init.

Comment: Well technically, hook_node_presave tells when a node is ABOUT to be saved, but it covers both new and existing nodes.  Depending on your requirements you may need a combination of hook_node_update and hook_node_insert instead.

Comment: Just wondering if Rules will be of some help here?

Comment: Yeah probably, that would be another option as long as the Message module has rules integration.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module

> The Message module is the core of the [message stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145). It enables logging and displaying system events in a number of different use cases. Events that are recorded over time are sometimes call activity streams. Exportable messages subtypes can be created for different use cases with custom fields and display (view) modes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply. But can you be more precise as how to send mail/sms notification when a user checks the checkbox (for ex:user 1 has places bid for $15 ,as soon as he places bid an mail/sms notification should be sent to other users stating about the highest bid uptil now).